# Background Image not showing up in jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I do not know what the problem is. I made a style.css and used this as my code

```
.jumbotron {
    background-image:url(images/bikebg.jpg);
    margin-top:-20px
}
```

before putting the background in the images folder, it worked fine. But since I changed it, it will no longer work. The site is live here http://bikesite.web44.net/bikes.html

Comment: which jumbotron???,whichj image ??\

Comment: your image path is wrong

Comment: The main image at the top. It should look like this http://prntscr.com/5al606

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
   .jumbotron {
        background-image:url(../images/bikebg.jpg);
        margin-top:-20px
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

your folder path was wrong

try

```
url(../images/bikebg.jpg);
```